# Use default MySQL function when retrieving a record on GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I have a model with this definition (simplified version):

```
type MyModel struct {
    ID                int64  `gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT"`
    Uuid              string `gorm:"type:binary(16);index:uuid_idx;default:(UUID_TO_BIN(UUID(), true));"`
}
```

I'm using `UUID_TO_BIN` with the `swap_flag` ([docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid)) to get better performance.

I would like to know if there is a way to tell GORM to use `BIN_TO_UUID(uuid, true)` over my column `Uuid` by default when querying a row from `MyModel`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to execute a function before retrieving a value is to use `Select` like this:

```golang
db.Select("id, BIN_TO_UUID(uuid) AS uuid").First(&myModel)
```

This isn't ideal, because you have to always remember to do that whenever you query that model.

A better way to do this is to look at building a [Custom Data Type](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html). Specifically you can create your own type that implements the GormDataTypeInterface to have Gorm assign the right DB column type, and custom `Scan/Value` functions that will do the conversion to and from binary instead of relying on MySQLs functions.

This will look something like this:

```golang
type MyUUID string 

// GormDataType implements the GormDataTypeInterface 
func (u MyUUID) GormDataType() string {
    return "varbinary(16)" 
}

// Scan implements the sql.Scanner interface
func (u *MyUUID) Scan(v interface{}) error {
    // Transform v (a []byte value from the database) into 
    // a string representation and assign to u 
}

// Value implement driver.Valuer interface
func (s MyUUID) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    // Return a []byte representation of s
}
```

Also good to read the docs on [`driver.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Value) and [`sql.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner).

You could implement these using some of the existing UUID go libraries, though the [linked one](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid) for example only handles Scanning from binary, its [Valuer implementation](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid/blob/master/sql.go#L30) returns the UUID as a string and that will trip up MySQL.